# how to get ID of inserted rows and update rows?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to get ids in my table then update
id row is auto increment

```
if (isset($_POST['reply'])) {
    $reply = $_POST['reply'];
    $answers = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table_name");
    while($answers_ = $answers->fetch_object()){
        if($get_answer = $db->query("UPDATE table_name SET answer ='$reply' WHERE question_id = '$answers_->question_id' LIMIT 1")){
            echo "done";    
        }
    }
}
```

I know my code is wrong its update all rows with the same value i want to update only one row

Answer (score 2):

use `mysqli_insert_id()` — Returns the auto generated id used in the last queryn

```
$get_answer = $db->query("UPDATE table_name SET answer ='$reply' WHERE question_id = '$answers_->question_id' LIMIT 1")

$last_id = mysql_insert_id();
```